# How to transform tree in text format with nesting levels designated by numbers

Tags: linux, bash

I'd appreciate your advice on how to transform (preferably with bash) text file, say foobar.txt, that stores information about directory structure in the following format:

1 qwe

2 rty

1 uio

1 asd

2 fgh

3 jkl

2 zxc

The first digit of every line designates the nesting level (7 is the largest value). I need to create the corresponding directory tree on disk. The command «xargs -a foobar.txt mkdir -p» will create the tree, but content of foobar.txt has to look like:

./qwe/rty

./uio

./asd/fgh/jkl

./asd/zxc

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with awk.  This will simply print the desired directories:

```
awk '{dir[$1]=$2; for( i in dir ) { if( i<=$1 ) { if( i==1 ) printf("."); printf("/%s", dir[i]); }} printf("\n"); }' text_file
```

And of course, you can just tack on the mkdir after it to create them:

```
awk '{dir[$1]=$2; for( i in dir ) { if( i<=$1 ) { if( i==1 ) printf("."); printf("/%s", dir[i]); }} printf("\n"); }' text_file | xargs mkdir -p
```

Comment: Works just great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
cat > foobar.txt << END
1 qwe
2 rty
1 uio
1 asd
2 fgh
3 jkl
2 zxc
END

# bash version

#!/bin/bash
{
path=(.)
while read dep dir; do
    ((dep <= ${#path[@]} && dep >= 1)) || {
        echo "invalid input $dep $dir"
        break
    }
    if ((dep < ${#path[@]})); then
        echo "$(IFS=/;echo "${path[*]}")"
        while ((dep < ${#path[@]})); do
            unset path[-1]
        done
    fi
    path+=("$dir")
done
echo "$(IFS=/;echo "${path[*]}")"
}  < foobar.txt

# perl equivalent
perl -nle '
    BEGIN{@path=(".")}
    ($depth,$dir)=/(\d+) (.*)/;
    die "invalid input $_" unless $depth;
    if ($depth!=@path) {
        print join "/", @path;
        pop @path while $depth != @path
    }
    push @path,$dir;
    END {print join "/", @path;}
'< foobar.txt
```

Comment: It also works perfectly (both bash and perl versions). I appreciate your help.